# HSTS setup in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https, hsts

I am trying to pass the test on https://hstspreload.org/ - However I am getting the following error below:

```
Error: Subdomain `www.test.com` is a subdomain. Please preload `test.com` instead. (Due to the size of the preload list and the behaviour of cookies across subdomains, we only accept automated preload list submissions of whole registered domains.)
```

(test.com was added to hide the domain)

My .htaccess file looks as following for HTTPS and HSTS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.test.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So what is your question? The message you get is crystal clear: "www.example.com" is a subdomain of "example.com". That is obviously correct. And the service states that it only accepts domains for a test, not subdomains. Your rewriting rules all target the subdomain, not the domain.

Comment: How do I rewrite the rules to target the main domain?

Comment: That is not seriously a question you ask, is it? Take a look at _your_ code and you should see the answer to _your_ question. If there is one specific details you fail to solve, that is something else, then please ask a _specific_ question. But the general question you just asked is nothing we need to answer. You can figure that out yourself. You know, when asking here, then you are expected to understand how the tools that you are using actually work or that you are willing to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the HTTPS rule before the www rule.
This worked for me :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```